# How to link Txt file key and entity values to the javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on Event calendar. Wherein I have to add the events to the calendar from the external txt file. How can i interlink the key values and entities to the JavaScript?. The event should be displayed correctly based on what i have given in the txt file.
Thank in Advance,

```
Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../lib/Theme/jquery-ui.min.css' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<li src='../events.txt'></li>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                right: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-04-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            events: [
            {
                    title: ' ',
                    start: ' '
                }
            ]
        });

    });
[Txt file][1]

[1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw3XnR8_0rzCVEpVMlpHNm41bUk
```

Comment: you'll need to use some AJAX method to read `events.txt`

Comment: Can you please explain??..

Comment: sure, I googled getting started with ajax, and found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sometext.txt",
    success: function(data) {
       processData(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
       console.log("Something broke.");
    }
})
```

I would suggest storing the data in [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp), so that no further processing is neccessary. Like so:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Probosys Meeting",
        "start": "2017-04-01"
    },
    {
        "title": "Probosys Starting",
        "start": "2017-04-03"
    },
    {
        "title": "Probosys Fucntion",
        "start": "2017-04-06"
    }
]
```

Comment: in the txt file I have the event details like Date , time and the name of the event, is that what you mean by "data", should I convert it into a JSON file and use it too? please explain, I am a beginner so sorry if the question seems a bit bland

Comment: You will get only your text in `data`, so you will need to parse it somehow to be able to pass them into `fullCalendar()`. As that function takes `events` as JSON, yes, you will have to parse your `data` to JSON.